# Create records in Salesforce from CSV file stored at server location

Tags: data-loader, ftp

I have a requirement to read a CSV file stored at location/server and upsert the records in Salesforce.
Can anyone suggest possible solution/ways to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can hit the URL using Rest webservice and parse the data and create records.
You can use Batch or Future to achieve this.

http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/